# Converting ogg base64 to other audio format for using speech-to-text

Tags: javascript, node.js, base64, ogg, google-speech-to-text-api

I am using speech-to-text service and unfortunately the 'OPUS' encoding does not work for my content, or any other audio/ogg content that is not corrupted.

There is a way to convert audio/ogg bufferArray/base64 to other audio format in base 64 using node.js?

Comment: Could you please expand more about what are you referring to your OPUS file content doesn't work? opus ogg is a compatible audio format for Speech to Text.
Also, what do you mean with “audio/ogg bufferArray/base64”? Did you convert your ogg audio to base64-encoded data?  And, now you are trying to  convert this  base64-encoded file to another type format such as mp3,flac …  and keep the base64 encoding?

Comment: Thank you for your response.
i am uploading audio/ogg file to firebase storage and get a signedUrl of the file.
then, using axios, i am downloading the file from the signedUrl using responseType:'arraybuffer'.
speech-to-text required base-64 format, so after getting the arraybuffer, i am converting him using arraybuffer.toString('base64') and sending the content to speech-to-text using the following configuration:
const config = {
                encoding:'OGG_OPUS',
                sampleRateHerts:16000,
                languageCode:'en-US'
            }

Comment: Use fs.readFileSync(filename).toString('base64') in order to encode data. Check the example of encoding audio content.https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/base64-encoding#embedding_audio_content_programmatically
Also, Speech-to-text can recognize directly on an audio file located in Cloud Storage using the URL.https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/sync-recognize#performing_synchronous_speech_recognition_on_a_remote_file. Probably it could be a good approach for your use-case.